# Regex for matching single,double an no quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use `preg_replace` function that has to clear all the `rel` and `target` attributes from the `$body` and to replace them with other values. Here it is:

```
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[] = '/<a(.*) rel="([^"]*)"(.*)>/';
    $patterns[] = '/<a(.*) target="([^"]*)"(.*)>/';
    $patterns[] = '/<a(.*)>/';

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[] = '<a$1$3>';
    $replacements[] = '<a$1$3>';
    $replacements[] = '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank"$1>';

    $body = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$body);
```

The problem is that it does not match single and no-quotes. 
Also if there is any better approach for clearing the `rel` and `target` attributes from the links and setting them with others, please advise.

Thanks

EDIT: `$body`:

```
    $body = '<a href="TEST">Link1</a>
      <a href="TEST" rel=\'lqlqlq\'>Link2</a>
      <a href="TEST" target="_blank" rel="lqlqlq">Link3</a>
              <a href="TEST" target=_blank rel=lqlqlq>Link4</a>';
```

And also every other option for working links due to the text is user defined and probably some users are going to cheat. My goal - all of the links in `$body` to be with defined `rel` and `target` attributes no matter what the user has entered.

Comment: Can you provide a fragment of the source text?

Comment: in regex you can write ["']? which means double, single quotes both optional

Comment: You can use SimpleXML or other XML library to scan your source and getting the elements more cleanly

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to parse HTML using regex, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and realize you're doing _EVIL_ things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match anything else at the same time I suggest you don't and preserve system resources.

```
$patterns[] = "/rel=[\"\']?([\w]+)[\"\']?/";
$patterns[] = "/target=[\"\']?([_a-zA-Z]+)[\"\']?/"
```

I'm not the best at REGEX but as far as I know this will save you some time.

Comment: great, did the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it matches them but due to the fact that `<a(.*)>` will always match no matter what the first two did, you won't get any results from the first two pattern.

This could do what you're looking for:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[] = '/<a(.*) rel=[\'"]?\S+[\'"]? (.*)>/';
$patterns[] = '/<a(.*) target=[\'"]?\S+[\'"]? (.*)>/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[] = '<a$1$3>';
$replacements[] = '<a$1$3>';

$body = preg_replace($patterns,$replacements,$body);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

this expression will handle 3 options:

1. no quotes
2. double quotes
3. single quotes

> '/href=["\']?([^"\'>]+)["\']?/'